# Opencart: make separate login page using ajax request response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, opencart2.x

i have two pages in opencart 1) demo.php and 2)response.php
i m sending email and password from demo.php to validate in response.php and give back response

demo.php page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        var data = {"action": "test"};
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/catalog/controller/account/response.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                    "Email" + data["email"] + "<br />Password" + data["password"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]   );              
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="return.php" class="js-ajax-php-json" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
  <input type="text" name="password" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit form"  />
</form>
<div class="the-return">
  [HTML is replaced when successful.]
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and response.php page

```
<?php
if (is_ajax()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { case "test": test(); break;   }//Switch case for value of action
    }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test(){
    $return = $_POST;
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

this work properly when i added this code it will not working in

response.php

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/home/abc/public_html/abc/catalog//';

if (file_exists($root . 'config.php')) { require_once($root . 'config.php');}
if (file_exists($root . 'system/startup.php')) { require_once($root . 'system/startup.php');}
if (file_exists($root . 'system/library/login.php')) { require_once($root . 'system/library/login.php');}

/**********************/
/**********************/
if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) 
    { case "test": test(); break; } //Switch case for value of action
  }
}
//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}
/**********************/
/**********************/

$user = new login();

function test(){
if ($user->login('username','password')) 
  { $data1 = array();
    $data1[] = 'hello';
    $noreturn = $data1;
    $noreturn["json"] = json_encode($noreturn);
    echo json_encode($noreturn);} 
else  
  { $return = $_POST;
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);}  
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the ControllerAccountResponse class and extend the Controller. Also, you can call a function from the url in OpenCart. Change the url to index.php and use the route parameter to find the correct controller. The first two items in the route parameter are the directory and the file and the third is the function you want to call.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".js-ajax-php-json").submit(function(){
        var data = {"action": "test"};
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "index.php?route=account/response/yourfunction",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $(".the-return").html(
                    "Email" + data["email"] + "<br />Password" + data["password"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]   );              
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller:

```
<?php
class ControllerAccountResponse extends Controller {  
    public function yourfunction() { 
        //Validate the response
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Trevor its working--------My Code------response.php--------------`<?php   
class ControllerAccountResponse extends Controller {    
    public function yourfunction() {   
    $this->load->model('account/customer');  
if ($this->customer->login($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))    
  { $data1 = array();   
    $data1[] = 'hello';     
    $noreturn = $data1;     
    $noreturn["json"] = json_encode($noreturn);     
    echo json_encode($noreturn);}     
else     
  { $return = $_POST;   
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);   
    echo json_encode($return);}     
    }
} ?>`